# InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found. (0) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [4,3] vs. [4,4]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, multiclass-classification

I am facing below error when trying to train a multi-class classification model ( 4 classes) for Image dataset.
Even though my output tensor is of shape 4 I am facing below issue.
Please let me know how to fix this issue.

```
    Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-01c6f78f4d4f> in <module>
      4     epochs=epochs,
      5     validation_data=val_data_gen,
----> 6     validation_steps=total_val // batch_size
      7 )

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1294         shuffle=shuffle,
   1295         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
-> 1296         steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
   1297 
   1298   def evaluate_generator(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py in model_iteration(model, data, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch, mode, batch_size, steps_name, **kwargs)
    263 
    264       is_deferred = not model._is_compiled
--> 265       batch_outs = batch_function(*batch_data)
    266       if not isinstance(batch_outs, list):
    267         batch_outs = [batch_outs]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics)
   1015       self._update_sample_weight_modes(sample_weights=sample_weights)
   1016       self._make_train_function()
-> 1017       outputs = self.train_function(ins)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
   1018 
   1019     if reset_metrics:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   3474 
   3475     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals,
-> 3476                                 run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   3477     self._call_fetch_callbacks(fetched[-len(self._fetches):])
   3478     output_structure = nest.pack_sequence_as(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1470         ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
   1471                                                self._handle, args,
-> 1472                                                run_metadata_ptr)
   1473         if run_metadata:
   1474           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [4,3] vs. [4,4]
     [[{{node loss_2/predictions_loss/logistic_loss/mul}}]]
     [[loss_2/mul/_19047]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [4,3] vs. [4,4]
     [[{{node loss_2/predictions_loss/logistic_loss/mul}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

**My batch size is 4 and below is last few layers of my model.**

```
conv5_block16_2_conv (Conv2D)   (None, 16, 16, 32)   36864       conv5_block16_1_relu[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv5_block16_concat (Concatena (None, 16, 16, 1024) 0           conv5_block15_concat[0][0]       
                                                                 conv5_block16_2_conv[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bn (BatchNormalization)         (None, 16, 16, 1024) 4096        conv5_block16_concat[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
relu (Activation)               (None, 16, 16, 1024) 0           bn[0][0]                         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
avg_pool (GlobalAveragePooling2 (None, 1024)         0           relu[0][0]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
predictions (Dense)             (None, 4)            4100        avg_pool[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
```

**Loss function**

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True))
```

Comment: are you sure your loss would be `binaryCrossentropy`? you have 4 output for predictions, try `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy`

Comment: If I use SparseCategoricalCrossentropy

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [4,3] and labels shape [16]
  [[{{node loss_4/predictions_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]]
  [[loss_4/mul/_29295]]
  (1) Invalid argument: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [4,3] and labels shape [16]
  [[{{node loss_4/predictions_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]]

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is nothing wrong with the shapes, but with the loss function, you are trying to use. Ideally for multiclass classification, the final layer has to have **softmax** activation (for your logits to sum up to 1) and use **CategoricalCrossentropy** as your loss function if your labels are one-hot and **SparseCategoricalCrossentropy** if your labels are integers. Tensorflow documentation attached below.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy

Changes that are to be done to your code

```
    # adding softmax activation to final dense layer 
    predictions = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(avg_pool)
    # assuming you have one-hot labels 
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True))
```

Comment: If I change to **softmax** and loss to **categorical**, I am getting below error

`InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[4,3] labels_size=[4,4]
  [[{{node loss_2/predictions_loss/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits}}]]
  [[loss_2/mul/_15371]]
  (1) Invalid argument: logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[4,3] labels_size=[4,4]
  [[{{node loss_2/predictions_loss/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.`

Comment: try removing `activation='softmax`

Comment: I'm not sure why you are still getting the logits_size = [4,3]. Can you post the whole code or the relevant code to regenerate the error?

Comment: I am loading my model with pre-trained weights ( which is trained for different no of classes) this is the issue.
Changing the name of final layer and loading weights with option by_name=True fixed the issue.
Thanks for the help Sriram and Shubham