# Tensorflow InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found. indices[28,0] = 11292 is not in [0, 11272)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I've created a model using Keras Sequential API, and using [Glove pretraining embeddings](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/)

```
def create_model(
        input_length=20,
        output_length=20):

    encoder_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(input_length,))
    decoder_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(output_length,))

    encoder = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(original_embedding_matrix.shape[0], original_embedding_dim, weights=[original_embedding_matrix], mask_zero=True)(encoder_input)
    encoder, h_encoder, u_encoder = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_state=True)(encoder)

    decoder = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(clone_embedding_matrix.shape[0], clone_embedding_dim, weights=[clone_embedding_matrix], mask_zero=True)(decoder_input)
    decoder = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(decoder, initial_state=[h_encoder, u_encoder])
    decoder = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(clone_vocab_size+1))(decoder)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[encoder_input, decoder_input], outputs=[decoder])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

model = create_model()
```

Here are my encoder/decoder shapes:

```
training_encoder_input.shape --> (2500, 20) 
training_decoder_input.shape --> (2500, 20) 
training_decoder_output.shape ---> (2500, 20, 11272) 
clone_vocab_size ---> 11271
```

Ouput of `model.summary()`:

```
Model: "functional_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 20)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 20)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding (Embedding)           (None, 20, 50)       564800      input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)         (None, 20, 50)       563600      input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                     [(None, 64), (None,  29440       embedding[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                   (None, 20, 64)       29440       embedding_1[0][0]                
                                                                 lstm[0][1]                       
                                                                 lstm[0][2]                       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistribut (None, 20, 11272)    732680      lstm_1[0][0]                     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,919,960
Trainable params: 1,919,960
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

But when I try to train the model:

```
model.fit(x=[training_encoder_input, training_decoder_input],
          y=training_decoder_output,
          verbose=2,
          batch_size=128,
          epochs=10)
```

I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  indices[28,0] = 11292 is not in [0, 11272)
     [[node functional_1/embedding_1/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-11-967d0351a90e>:31) ]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  indices[28,0] = 11292 is not in [0, 11272)
     [[node functional_1/embedding_1/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-11-967d0351a90e>:31) ]]
     [[broadcast_weights_1/assert_broadcastable/AssertGuard/else/_13/broadcast_weights_1/assert_broadcastable/AssertGuard/Assert/data_7/_78]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_13975]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node functional_1/embedding_1/embedding_lookup:
 functional_1/embedding_1/embedding_lookup/8859 (defined at /usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py:81)

Input Source operations connected to node functional_1/embedding_1/embedding_lookup:
 functional_1/embedding_1/embedding_lookup/8859 (defined at /usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py:81)

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function
```

Someone already asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61054359/invalidargumenterror-2-root-errors-found-0-invalid-argument-incompatible) but none of the reponses worked for me, probably the error is within the loss function or within the vocabulary of the embedding layer, but I can't figure out what's exactly the problem.

Comment: how did you generate training_encoder_input and training_decoder_input ?

Comment: Using Keras `Tokenizer` and `pad_sequences` for equalize the length.

Comment: what I can suggest is this: https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-word-embedding-layers-deep-learning-keras/, the section when the pretrained glove is used

Comment: I checked the tutorial but didn't find any solution, anyway thanks for your response

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple in fact, in the error:

```
(0) Invalid argument:  indices[28,0] = 11292 is not in [0, 11272)
```

- `11292` is an input element (mapped to a word in my Tokenizer dictionary)
- `11272` is the lenght of my vocabulary

Why do I have a word with number `11292` if the length of my tokenizer is just `11272`?

- I have two tokenizers, one for the input and other for the output, so a solution would be to take the lenght of the smaller ans use it in the model.

You can also limit the number of words used in the tokenizer in Tensorflow:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=20000)
```

and it will take the 20000 most repeated words.