# keras class_weights creates the error "InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:"

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, time-series

I am training a time series LSTM model on Keras for a binary classification problem. 
The labels are quite unbalanced (0s are ~75%).
That influenced my results, and therefore I decided to correct for this (especially since I want to reduce false positives).

My model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), use_bias=True, unroll=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(.25))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=False, use_bias=True, unroll=True))
model.add(Dense(num_points_per_inp, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(beta_1=.8, beta_2=.9), loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy())  # loss=weighted_binary_crossentropy, metrics='accuracy')
model.summary()
```

I tried different permutations of BN and DO, but if there is an issue here please still let me know.

Input sizes are:

```
X_train.shape  --> (8000, 100, 4)
X_test.shape  --> (2000, 100, 4)
y_train.shape  --> (8000, 100)
y_test.shape  --> (2000, 100)
```

When running this without class_weights, the model compiles and trains, but when I add class_weights, it produces this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-2ebc95d5f9f5> in <module>()
      7                     validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
      8                     class_weight=weights,
----> 9                     verbose=1)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  indices[2] = 52 is not in [0, 2)
     [[{{node GatherV2}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[IteratorGetNext/_2]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  indices[2] = 52 is not in [0, 2)
     [[{{node GatherV2}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_769866]
```

The class_weights were generated in two different ways (both did not work):
method 1:

```
# based on https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html
from sklearn.utils import class_weight

w = class_weight.compute_class_weight(
          class_weight = 'balanced', 
          classes = np.unique(y_train), 
          y = y_train.flatten())
weights = dict(enumerate(np.round(w,2)))
```

method 2:

```
# based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6awaKc1L-Q (@ ~12mins)
counts = np.bincount(y_train.flatten().astype(int))
w0 = 1 / counts[0]
w1 = 1 / counts[1]
weights = {0: w0, 1: w1}
```

My assumption is that the problem is related to the fact that I have 100 time points in each prediction (?), while the examples I saw had only 1 each time. But even here I'm not sure.

Trying with categorical cross-entropy, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61054359/invalidargumenterror-2-root-errors-found-0-invalid-argument-incompatible) also did not help

**How can I resolve this?**

---

I also tried other methods, i.e. - custom loss, but they also did not work as expected:

```
import keras.backend as K
def weighted_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
  weights =(tf.math.abs(y_true) * 59.) + 1.
  bce = K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
  weighted_bce = K.mean(bce * weights)
  return weighted_bce
```

(adapted from [this medium article](https://medium.com/dataseries/how-to-deal-with-unbalanced-dataset-in-binary-classification-part-3-e580d8d09883))

Any suggestions how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today.  The issue is that class weighting doesn't work for multi-dimensional outputs

To work around this you can use sample weighting instead, basically you would need to create an array with the same shape as `y_train` minus the last dimension (assuming you are using one-hot encoding), with the weight for each example, then pass this with the `sample_weight` argument to `model.fit`.